# Expressão regular para extrair os valores decimais

Tags: regex

Com a seguinte expressão **(,)([0-9]*)** consegui pegar o valor ',25', mas gostaria de pegar apenas o número '25', sem a vírgula.

decimal(10,25)

Neste caso, como desconsidero a vírgula (**,**)?

Comment: Considere informar a linguagem de programação que você está utilizando Iago, pois as implementações das regex podem variar entre as linguagens.

Answer (score 9):

Se o que você quer é simplesmente deixar só o número em um grupo de captura é só tirar a virgula dos parênteses:

```
,([0-9]*)
```

Para garantir que tem algum número pode usar o `+` ao invés do `*` (pode usar o `\d` ao invés de `[0-9]` se quiser):

```
,(\d+)
```

Comment: amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda, das opções escolhi a sua como melhor alternativa.

Comment: Ok, @IagoLeão! Considere marcar a resposta como aceita então.

Answer (score 5):

Use a seguinte expressão regular que irá funcionar:

```
(?<=,)([0-9]+)
```

Essa expressão regular usa `lookbehind` que nada mais é que encontrar os valores do grupo definido `([0-9]+)` se antes dele encontrar a vírgula `(?<=,)`.

Uma explicação complete sobre `lookahead` e `lookbehind` pode ser encontrada [neste site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Segue um exeplo de código com Python:

```
import re
m = re.search('(?<=,)([0-9]+)', '(0,25)')
print m.group(0) #25
```

Comment: Não sei a linguagem que OP tá usando, mas gostaria de alertar ele que essa sua resposta, até onde eu saiba, não funciona em JavaScript (por exemplo) por falta de suporte a lookbehinds.

Answer (score -2):

Um código para retirar valores decimais e para manipular valores decimais (se existirem).
Para retirar e manipular valores decimais com (.) é só mudar a expressão regular retirando a virgula e colocando ponto. /,([1-9]+)/ => /.([1-9]+)/

```
const value = '10,15';
console.log(value)
// verifica se tem virgula e se é um valor diferente de 00
const hasCents = value.search(/,([1-9]+)/);
if (hasCents !== -1) {
    // retira os centavos|valor decimal
    let cents = value.slice(-2);
    // valor sem decimal
    let newValue = value.slice(0, hasCents);
    console.log(newValue, cents);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Apenas use `(,25)`,pega todas as ocorrencias de ,25.

`\w,(25*)` para o número completo.

Teste no [Regexr](http://www.regexr.com/)

Comment: ele deseja retornar somente o números depois da vírgula, não a vírgula e somente o número 25

Comment: Verdade...Vou manter a resposta para verem como não se faz.